# Cloudflare Workers with Webassembly

Tags: c#, api, webassembly

i managed today to get cloudflare workers working with my c# wasm. My question is, how safe this is if i want to serve a api on workers with webassembly? I want to connect a database to that, so if i now have the webassemly uploaded at cloudflare workers, if i open it, does my browser run the db request, when i run it in the code? Or does Cloudflare manage it somehow, that the user dont get the database logins?

I am trying to have a fast scaleable Api for my WebApp and i was interested, if this could be used for a backend?

Thanks!

Comment: It runs on Cloudflare, the browser merely get the result of the request. Do note the 100k daily request limit on free tier.

Comment: thanks, so its safe? How can i check if to much gets outside?

Comment: You can just call it on your browser and check the downloaded resource (should be nearly nothing)

Comment: thats not the case, i used the html example on github and i think its sending everything. I have a c# Asp.net api currently and i want to switch to cloudflare. There i dont need asp.net, but how should i route it?

Comment: Which example? Include your code

Comment: This here: https://github.com/cloudflare/worker-sites-template and i put my webassembly into public

Comment: yea i asume thats the problem, but how do i assemble a api in c# via webassemble to cloudflare?

Comment: I'm guessing the 'public' folder is the static web app, which is always sent down to the browser and not run on CloudFlare's servers. You would have to get your WebAssembly code running from the 'workers-site' folder.

Answer (score 0):

So i researched a lot and currently it seems that doesn't work. The Only way is via Cloudflare Pages and Blazor for a static site, there you could make routes and requests, but they are client sided... Maybe this changes in .Net 7

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31700481)